# How to get result from DB in batches of 1k or 2k?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm stuck with a requirement .I'm using Spring boot with hibernate criteria for querying my db .

I have `Messages` table with 100k records .

```
Message ID | Message Text | RequestID | Request Type | Scheduled on     | Validity date   | IS_PROCESSED |
-----------|--------------|-----------|--------------|------------------|-----------------|--------------|
1          | Sample 1     |  11       | Parent       |  28-01-2021 15:47|31-01-2021 15:40 |  0           |
2          | Sample 2     |  11       | Parent       |  28-01-2021 15:47|31-01-2021 15:40 |  0           |
3          | Sample 3     |  11       | Parent       |  28-01-2021 15:47|31-01-2021 15:40 |  0           |
4          | Sample 4     |  12       | Parent       |  28-01-2021 15:40|31-01-2021 15:40 |  0           |
5          | Sample 5     |  12       | Parent       |  28-01-2021 15:40|31-01-2021 15:40 |  0           |
6          | Sample 6     |  12       | Parent       |  28-01-2021 15:40|31-01-2021 15:40 |  0           |
7          | Sample 7     |  12       | Parent       |  28-01-2021 15:40|31-01-2021 15:40 |  0           |
8          | Sample 8     |  13       | Parent       |  28-01-2021 15:40|31-01-2021 15:40 |  0           |
9          | Sample 9     |  14       | Parent       |  28-01-2021 15:44|31-01-2021 15:40 |  0           |
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
1000000   | Sample100000 |  500       | Parent       |  28-01-2021 15:47|31-01-2021 15:40 |  0           |
```

Each Request can have 'N' number of messages that can be scheduled .
More than one request can be scheduled at same time , ie,. Two or more request can be scheduled for "28-01-2021 15:40" with 'N' records each.(Request 1 can have 50k records and Request 2 can have 10k records)

I'm running a scheduled method with fires up for each minute to check if any messages has been scheduled for that minute .
28-01-2021 15:40 - say 15k

28-01-2021 15:41 - say 10k

28-01-2021 15:42 - nothing

28-01-2021 15:43 - nothing

28-01-2021 15:44 - say 50k

Note : Rows in table are not in the ascending order of scheduled time .

**Query**

```
Date date=new Date();                             //28-01-2021 15:40
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(POJO.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("scheduleDate", date));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("deliveryStatus", Constants.MSG_PENDING));
msgList=criteria.list();
```

The result returned back is stored in list which is consuming too much memory .I need a way to get records in batches , like 1k or 2k record each second and process them . I tried `Limit and offset` through `setmaxresults()` of hibernate criteria , but If I'm firing it for each minute , the offset value gets corrupted if i have more records.

Please suggest a way to get 1k or 2k records each second/minute from DB through query and process them.

Comment: Use `scroll()` instead of `list()` which will get you a lazy cursor. Then iterate over that stream instead of the list. Will save you memory and performance due to less GC cycles. Or, when using JPA 2.2, use the regular JPA API and use `getResultStream` to get an actual `java.util.stream.Stream`.

Comment: @Deinum , Will it work for my scenario ?? because I will be firing the same query each minute .

Comment: Why wouldn't it. If it works with a list it works with a stream.

Comment: But it would be still loading all 10k or 50k records into memory ? right?

Comment: No. It will only load that row that is being processed. After that it will be garbage collected and the next row loaded. That with an increased fetch size on the JDBC side will increase your performance and reduce the used memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually solved by using keyset pagination. You need a stable keyset e.g. `(scheduleDate, id)` and remember the last processed keyset. In the next run, you use that keyset to do a query like `(scheduleDate, id) > (:previousScheduleDate, :previousId)`

Comment: can you please brief your answer . I don't understand how it will work for my issue . I'm firing the query each minute for 24/7

Comment: You will have to persist the last processed keyset somewhere so you can make use of that again in the next run. If you ask specific questions I can answer them, but I think i outlined everything that you need to implement this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pagination in Hibernate with Criteria API - to get n numbers of records.

```
int pageNumber = 2;
int pageSize = 10;       
try {
    session.beginTransaction();
     
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
    criteria.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
    criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
     
    List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>) criteria.list();
    if (employees!=null) {
        System.out.println("Total Results:" + employees.size());
        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            System.out.println(employee.getId() + " - " + employee.getName());
        }
    }             
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (HibernateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

Comment: This is for pagination . This doesn't address my issue

Comment: You want to limit number of records which  you can do by setMaxResults() but then next time when scheduler runs you would require to fetch next batch of n records hence setFirstResult(). Otherwise every time when the scheduler runs you will get same records considering the limit is set.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Spring data JPA, Spring Data JPA provides way to implement pagination with [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html).

PagingAndSortingRepository extends CrudRepository to provide additional methods to retrieve entities using the pagination abstraction.

```
public interface PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {
  Page<T> findAll([Pageable][2] pageable);
}
```

`findAll(Pageable pageable)`: returns a Page of entities meeting the paging condition provided by Pageable object.

Spring Data also supports many useful Query Creation from method names that we’re gonna use to filter result in this example such as:

```
Page<Tutorial> findByPublished(boolean published, Pageable pageable);
Page<Tutorial> findByTitleContaining(String title, Pageable pageable);
```

This is how we create Pageable objects using PageRequest class which implements Pageable interface:

```
Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size);
```

page: zero-based page index, must NOT be negative.
size: number of items in a page to be returned, must be greater than 0.

Comment: This works for pagination . but my issue is not related to pagination